# Changing scrolling behavior - good use cases?

Tags: interface, scrolling, javascript

Some websites modify scrolling behavior, e.g. by changing scrolling speed, "smooth scrolling", or even [snapping to sections on scroll](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage).

Personally, I find it *incredibly* annoying to have my scrolling screwed with, *especially* snapping to sections of a page. This is primarily because I have to wait for the JavaScript to finish its nonsense before I can accurately scroll to where I *want* to, and *how* I want to.

Are there any **good** use cases for websites to modify scroll behavior, e.g. by changing the scroll speed, or 'snapping' to sections on scroll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### **No!** There are no good cases for ruining standard scrolling.

Standard scrolling of web pages is the page turning of web viewing.

Any **changes** **to standard scrolling are no longer standard scrolling**, and need their own interface.

There's plenty of options for fancy scrolling mechanisms and interfaces:

- Little highlights in the scroll bars for jump points
- direct inline links, colour annotated or otherwise indicated
- option buttons in conjunction with scrolling actions

Anyone presuming to ruin basic, standard scrolling should consider alternative interfaces before ruining the most common function of a browser, to "turn the page".

Which kind of brings to mind the idea that the "web page" metaphor might have become a bit odd in the face of scrolling being normalised since its inception as a description of "pages" on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Confused is not confused in his or her opinion and is very forthright, look at that bold heavy text!

Scrolling is changed in mouse settings, we can free wheel, adjust the lines each scroll moves, the physical button on some mice changes the feel of the scroll and pressing the mouse wheel often flicks between a grab and scroll setting.

It's not about what part of the UI you affect, it's about how you change it, how you inform your users that you've changed it, whether it has value and whether it is usable.

Such a fundamental part of many UI's, I can only suggest that the way you will know whether this has value is doing some user testing in a workshop scenario.